# Set theoretic limit for a monotone sequence

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I have a sequence $A_{n}$ which is non-decreasing, i.e., I have $A_{n} \subset A_{n+1}$. Assume for simplicity that: $$A_{n+1} = A_{n} \cup \{ n+1\}.$$
From [set-theoretic limit knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) we can see that:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_{n} = \bigcup_{j \geq 1} A_{n}.$$
It is straightforward to see that $\bigcup_{j = 1}^m A_{n} = A_{m}$.

So, my question is, can I simply conclude:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_{n} = \bigcup_{j \geq 1} A_{n} =\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} = A_{\infty}$$

I am not sure about the validity of the last step since $\bigcup_{j = 1}^m A_{n} = A_{m}$ property was for finite $ m$.

Comment: Yes because you know the limit exists. So you limit have a meaning and $A_\infty$ is defined here as the limit.

Answer (score 2):

If this is true, then the limit exists:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}infA_{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}supA_{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}A_{n}$$
It is important to know that the limits of sequences of sets sometimes do not share the properties of the elements of the sequence, for example consider the sequence of open intervals:
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N,  B_{n}=(-\frac{1}n,\frac{n+1}n) \quad and\quad  \lim_{n\to \infty}B_{n}=[0,1],\quad \Bbb B=\{\forall X\in \Bbb B|X=B_{n}\}  $$
In that sense, adding the limit to the set $\Bbb B$ will make it lose its property of being composed only of open sets.

By the way you write:
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^m A_{n}=A_{m}$$
But $n$ is not dependant on $j$. I think what you meant to write was :
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^m A_{j}=A_{m}$$

Comment: true, $j$ should be $n$, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any meaning to the string $A_{\infty}$ before using it.

Thus, you cannot *conclude* that $\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} = A_{\infty}$ because $A_{\infty}$ does not have any meaning.

However, you can *define* $A_{\infty}$ as $\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} = A_{\infty}$.

Comment: If $A_{0} = \{0\}$, how can I define $A_{\infty} = {1,2,3,\ldots,\infty}$?

Comment: $A_{\infty} = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ will start at $A_1$, and $A_{\infty} = \bigcup_{j = 0}^{\infty} A_{n}$, you can define it however you want